# Mechanism to upload S3 object in AWS account by external partner

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a use case where external partners needs to upload a large text file in my AWS account. Besides the option of pre-signed URL, is there any other automated mechanism via which the partner can upload the file in S3 bucket of my AWS account and notify me about the same by triggering my own REST API (exposed by API gateway) about that the object has been uploaded ?

Answer (score 0):

What about Cognito Identity Pools? It provides temporary credentials for users to access AWS Services like S3.

For the notification part, you can configure S3 to react after an event in the advanced settings of your S3.

Answer (score 0):

One solution here is for you to create an IAM role in your account that allows uploads to your S3 bucket (and no permissions beyond that). You then establish a cross-account trust on that IAM role for each partner's AWS account. They can then use their credentials to assume the role in your account and upload to your bucket.

To  notify you, or trigger some custom code to run, when a file has been uploaded, you can configure an S3 event trigger. This can publish a message to an SNS topic which you can subscribe to for notifications. Alternatively, trigger a Lambda function that executes arbitrary code.